# Create (Unwrap) a UV Map after Adding Texture to the Image Editor

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I was following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DNC2lNYtxFY

When the narrator hits u/Unwrap, his UV map shows up as rectangles, elongated to cover his entire image (at video marker 3:39). When I follow along, I get perfect squares over half my image and the rest of the image is falling out. What is he not showing, or what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YouTube is currently having issues (Oct 16th crash) so your video is unavailable.

A wild guess... if you've rescaled your object at any point you need to apply this change. Select the object you're unwrapping, `Tab` to **Object mode**, tap `Ctrl  + A` and choose **Scale**. Then try the unwrap again and see if this fixes your issue.

Edit: This appears to be a difference in the way UVs are unwrapped between the Internal renderer and the Cycles renderer. Switching to cycles and unwrapping gives the desired result.

Comment: Weird on the YouTube thing. I just posted this earlier today.

Comment: He does scale the plane as part of the tutorial (without showing the "apply" part), but I still got the same result. I also tried the tutorial without any scaling to begin with and got the same result.

Comment: YouTube is back up, and I see that you're in Blender Internal Engine. Change to Cycles Engine and re-do the unwrap.